# MySQL query works in phpmyadmin but no rows returned in PHP result set

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.*
FROM product AS p
LEFT JOIN productCategory AS c ON FIND_IN_SET(c.id, REPLACE(TRIM(p.categories), ' ',','))
WHERE (
    c.id IS NULL
    OR c.status = 'D'
    OR p.categories IS NULL
    OR TRIM(p.categories) = ''
)
AND p.deprecated = 'N'
LIMIT 0,30
```

This query is to pick up products which:

- Has something set in `p.categories` column, but the row on the `productCategory` table does not exist
- Have a `productCategory` row, but the status on the `productCategory` row is set to 'D'
- Have nothing set in the `p.categories` column

`p.categories` is a row with space separated numeric values representing ids on the `productCategory` table. Not the best design, granted but I have been given this task, so need a way of doing it.

In the PHP code, this query is executed directly afterwards:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as count
```

When executed from phpmyadmin, I get thousands of rows returned and when I append the second query, I get a count value of the correct number of rows. When I execute the same first query through mysqli_query(), I get no rows at all returned and the following query returns a count of 1.

Both phpmyadmin and my PHP code are connecting to the same database.

Can anyone see what is going wrong?!

**Update:**

I only want the first 30 rows returned because there could be a huge total number, in the subsequent query, I should get a count of what that total would be, hence SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS after the first SELECT.

Comment: Try adding a semi-colon after each statement.

Comment: When running the query through PHP, each is passed through mysqli_query() seperately, so no need. When in phpmyadmin, Yes, I do seperate them with a semi-colon.

Comment: Sidenote: you are not storing categories efficiently, this way DB engine has to do a string replace function on **ALL** product rows. You should have another table storing relations `post_id => category_id` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, changing the first line of the query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.*
```

To:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.id
```

And then looping through the results getting the data I needed from each row in separate queries got the result I was after.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform the first query only to get the record-set returned to PHP. You can count in your PHP once you have it. You shouldn't pass concatenated queries from PHP to MySQL.

i.e.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$recordCount = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: That would include all rows in the result, I only want the first 30 initially because there could be a huge number, followed by a count of what the total would be, hence SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS after the first SELECT. BTW: I am not concatenating queries, each one is in a seperate call to mysqli_query().