# mysql and php %like% query. Works in phpmyadmin but different results php

Tags: php, mysql

I have some search fields that look across a few different tables.

"display_name" form field and "last" form field show different results then what it does directly into phpmyadmin.

If i echo out the mysql query in my php script and paste it into phpmyadmin. It lists of correct results. However on the php/html page it is not listing the same.

For example. If someones name full name is nathan spencer and i put spencer into the "last" form field it will only show 1 result or 2 results. HOWEVER there are actually 5 results found by pasting it directly into phpmyadmin and running it.

I have been battling for ages with this and its driving me nuts.

Here is the PHP up the top of the page:

```
<?php
// SEARCH

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // define the list of fields
    $fields = array('display_name', 'last', 'suburb', 'state', 'user_type', 'active');
    $conditions = array();

    // loop through the defined fields
    foreach($fields as $field){
        // if the field is set and not empty
        if(isset($_POST[$field]) && $_POST[$field] != '') {
            // create a new condition while escaping the value inputed by the user (SQL Injection)
            $conditions[] = "`$field` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field])."%'";
        }
    }

    // builds the query
    $query = "SELECT display_name, first, last, suburb, state, user_type, active FROM nfw_users ";
    // if there are conditions defined
    if(count($conditions) > 0) {
        // append the conditions
        $query .= "WHERE " . implode (' AND ', $conditions) .""; // you can   change to 'OR', but I suggest to apply the filters cumulative
    }

    else {
        echo "No records found";
    }

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $score = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

}
?>
```

and here is the html form

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="display_name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Street:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="last" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suburb:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="suburb" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>State:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="state">
                      <option>
                      <option value="qld">QLD</option>
                      <option value="sa">SA</option>
                      <option value="nt">NT</option>
                      <option value="wa">WA</option>
                      <option value="vic">VIC</option>
                      <option value="tas">TAS</option>
                      <option value="act">ACT</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Type:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="user_type">
                      <option>
                      <option value="franchise">Franchisee</option>
                      <option value="regional">Regional</option>
                      <option value="state">State</option>
                      <option value="national">National</option>
                      <option value="office">Headoffice Staff</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Active:</td>
                 <td>
                    <select name="active">
                      <option></option>
                      <option value="1">Active</option>
                      <option value="0">Not Active</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></td>
            </tr>
        </form>

<form method="post" action="index.php">
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="display_name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Street:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="last" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suburb:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="suburb" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>State:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="state">
                      <option>
                      <option value="qld">QLD</option>
                      <option value="sa">SA</option>
                      <option value="nt">NT</option>
                      <option value="wa">WA</option>
                      <option value="vic">VIC</option>
                      <option value="tas">TAS</option>
                      <option value="act">ACT</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Type:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="user_type">
                      <option>
                      <option value="franchise">Franchisee</option>
                      <option value="regional">Regional</option>
                      <option value="state">State</option>
                      <option value="national">National</option>
                      <option value="office">Headoffice Staff</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Active:</td>
                 <td>
                    <select name="active">
                      <option></option>
                      <option value="1">Active</option>
                      <option value="0">Not Active</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
```

and here is the results that get printed into a table

```
<?php if(isset($score)){
while($score=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $display_name = $score['display_name'];
      $lastname = $score['last'];
      $state = $score['state'];
      $active = $score['active'];

      if ($active=='1') {
        $activeother = "<i class='fa fa-check' style='color:green;'></i>";
      }
      else {
        $activeother = "<i class='fa fa-times' style='color:red;'></i>";
      }
?>
<?php
$content = "<tr><td>" . $score['display_name'] . "</td><td>" . $score['first'] . "</td><td>" . $score['last'] . "  </td><td>" . $score['email'] . " </td><td> " . $score['mobile'] . " </td><td> " . $score['landline'] . "</td><td>$activeother</td><td> " . $score['user_type'] . "</td><td> " . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($score['date_join'])) . "</td><td class='invoicing-columns'><a class='btn btn-yellow' href='view-invoices.php?id=" . $score['id_num'] . "'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></a></td><td class='invoicing-columns'><a class='btn btn-red' href='del-customers.php?id=" . $score['id_num'] . "' onclick='return check();' class='delete'><i class='fa fa-minus-circle'></i></a></td></tr>";
echo $content;
}}
?>
```

Comment: Can you provide value of `$query` just before the  `$result = mysql_query($query);` string?

Comment: string(142) "SELECT display_name, first, last, suburb, state, user_type, active FROM nfw_users WHERE `display_name` LIKE '%nick%' AND `last` LIKE '%smith%'"

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL query works in phpmyadmin but no rows returned in PHP result set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147638/mysql-query-works-in-phpmyadmin-but-no-rows-returned-in-php-result-set)

Comment: It seems that you doing wrong checks and loop over the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your code right there might be issue:
Here you actually fetching first row.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$score = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Then it seems that you simply skip it and go with loop:

```
if(isset($score)){
while($score=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

What you really want to do is:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  //TODO: Query error handling
}

// This is how you check for results count
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
  while ($score = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   //Here you go with result
  }
}
```

*You can also check [this manual link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) as reference.*

Next thing to check, get exact string from query and try it from phpMyAdmin. Make sure that you use same user as your code does, when doing query.

And one more thing, extension you are using is long time deprecated, you should consider to switching to [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: Walked away, had dinner. Came back, Looked at my code and your solution and nailed it in 5 minutes. Thank you very much for your help. All fixed  :)